# jquery selection with many children

Tags: jquery, selection, children

I want to select the content of "Something" with jquery at the end of the following example, can someone help me maybe with this?

```
body.ext-gecko.ext-gecko3 
     div#scrollWrapper.scrollWrapper 
         div#wrapper 
            div#results.resultClass 
                div#slideAll.slideAll 
                    div#mainmenu.slideMenu 
                      ul#nav 
                        li 
                          ul 
                           li 
                             a#Something
```

Comment: It's an ID. It must be unique. `$('#Something')` should be all you could possibly need.

Comment: And answers go down there. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You should probably try looking it up in the jquery api.

`$('a#something').html()`

Answer (score 0):

The id is not unique, that is the problem, it is also used somewhere else in the code.